# Help me set up ssl.conf for multiple domains (name-based vhosts in ssl.conf?)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

In my httpd.conf:

If I have my virtual host configured as:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias www.foo.com
    Include conf.d/foo.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bar.com
    ServerAlias www.bar.com
    Include conf.d/bar.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Can I get by with a single domain SSL certificate or must I purchase a wildcard SSL certificate to handle the www subdomain?

I am now trying to configure the ssl.conf file, can I use name-based vhosts in my ssl.conf file like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias www.foo.com
    ...
    Include conf.d/foo.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName bar.com
    ServerAlias www.bar.com
    ...
    Include conf.d/bar.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

or do I need IP based vhosts? If this is possible, what kind of cert would I need in order to do this?

Comment: I reverted my edit.  Your question is not a repeat but a near duplicate of a very recent question.  http://serverfault.com/questions/123954/what-kind-of-ssl-cert-do-i-need-for-this-vhost-configuration/123958#123958

You might re-write it to clarify your question or delete it if it is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name based virtual hosts using SSL are possible, but require SNI : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browsers you expect to hit your site, you can use [SNI](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI)). Otherwise, you need to use IP based vhosts. A self-signed cert will work, but typically a basic SSL cert (about $100, or less) will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If both sites are on the same IP address, your best option is to use a [UC certificate](http://www.sslshopper.com/unified-communications-uc-ssl-certificates.html) that includes all four names (foo.com, www.foo.com, bar.com, www.bar.com). Then you don't have to worry about SNI which isn't fully supported yet or getting multiple IP addresses or getting a name mismatch error.